# Get response instead of error in redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I would like to know how can I handle an error response in redux saga, I'm still learning and I'm doing this:

```
export function* loginUserSaga(action) {
 try {
  const user = action.payload
  const responseData = yield call(loginUser, user);
  yield put(succeededLoginRequest(responseData));
 } catch (e) {
  yield put(failedLoginRequest(e.message));
 }
}
```

If there's another way to handle that so I can get the response instead of the error? As I seen in the docs normally you use a try catch for making requests to the API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try..catch is usually the way togo, but you can modify your loginUser response to return an object with response/error fields and then use a condition instead of try..catch.

This is an example from the docs (https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/ErrorHandling.html):

```
import Api from './path/to/api'
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function fetchProductsApi() {
  return Api.fetch('/products')
    .then(response => ({ response }))
    .catch(error => ({ error }))
}

function* fetchProducts() {
  const { response, error } = yield call(fetchProductsApi)
  if (response)
    yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', products: response })
  else
    yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_REQUEST_FAILED', error })
}
```